# Deprecated warning message in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

*setText* is deprecated warning message displayed at `UITableViewCell`

```
[cell setText:animal.name];
```

when compiling. But program is running properly.

Comment: Do you expect it to break? It's only deprecated. It shouldn't break.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `setText:` in [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text) has been deprecated.

Use the following instead of that.

```
[cell.textLabel setText:animal.name];
```